# Data recording and extraction software for C++

Tags: c++, extract, recording

I am interested to learn about what libraries, tools, or frameworks there are for having a C++ program record data for later analysis and extraction.  I provide a description of what I envision to give an idea of what I'm looking to do, but your suggestions need not fit it exactly.

I'd like to specify different record types for my program to record.  For example, there might be a distinct record type for each type of message I get from a device, a record type for the results of major algorithms, a record type for each kind of operator input.  Ideally the code changes for adding a new record type would be fairly minimal: Define a struct for the data to record, correlate it to a record type ID, and add the code to record instances to file.

After the main program runs, I'd like to run a data extraction tool that could give a summary of the data recorded and allow me to extract specific record types over a specified time period of the run.  I could provide the exec to the tool and it would use some of the same hooks a debugger tool uses to figure out the names of the fields in the struct for use in the extraction report.  It would be nice if the extraction report could be specified as .txt, .xml, .csv (for opening in Excel), or .hdf (for opening in Matlab).

This would be for Linux and GCC compiler.  Ideally suggestions would be FOSS, but proprietary solutions are welcome too.  Let me know!

Answer (score 1):

What you described isn't anything special. Just generic serialization and de-serialization. If you want some specific library you should describe what exactly you want to do with the recorded data.

For serialization support, look into [Boost::Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) and [s11n](http://s11n.net/).